# i've made a calculator but i have no idea how to show how the calculator did the math

Tags: javascript, html

I've made a calculator that works, it's not the prettiest, but it works and that's good enough for me since I'm pretty much a beginner at coding.

The last thing I'm missing is a little text box that shows the process of the calculation. an example would be "3+4=7".

I really appreciate every bit of help I can get. If you need any extra code from my files or anything then please let me know.

```js
    function calc() {
        
      var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n1").value);
      var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n2").value);
      var oper = document.getElementById("operators").value;

      if(oper === "+")
      {
        document.getElementById("result").value = n1+n2;
      }
      if(oper === "-")
      {
        document.getElementById("result").value = n1-n2;
      }
      if(oper === "/")
      {
        document.getElementById("result").value = n1/n2;
      }
      if(oper === "*")
      {
        document.getElementById("result").value = n1*n2;
      }
    }
```

```html
        <input type="number" id="n1"/>
        <input type="number" id="n2"/>
        
        <select id="operators">
          <option value="+">+</option>
          <option value="-">-</option>
          <option value="/">/</option>
          <option value="*">*</option>
        </select>
        
        <button onclick="calc();">sum</button>
        <input type="text" id="result">
```

Answer (score 1):

that should allow you to explore a little more in the world of JavaScript

```js
const in_N1     = document.getElementById('n1')
    , in_N2     = document.getElementById('n2')
    , Operator  = document.getElementById("operators")
    , btCalc    = document.getElementById('bt-Calc')
    , txtResult = document.getElementById('result')


btCalc.onclick=()=>
{
  let Result = 0
  switch (Operator.value) {
  case '+':
  Result = in_N1.valueAsNumber + in_N2.valueAsNumber
  break;
  case '-':
  Result = in_N1.valueAsNumber - in_N2.valueAsNumber
  break;
  case '/':
  Result = in_N1.valueAsNumber / in_N2.valueAsNumber
  break;
  case '*':
  Result = in_N1.valueAsNumber * in_N2.valueAsNumber
  break;
  }
  txtResult.appendChild( document.createTextNode(` ${in_N1.value}  ${Operator.value}  ${in_N2.value} = ${Result} \n`) )
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="n1" value="0"/>

<select id="operators">
  <option value="+" selected>+</option>
  <option value="-">-</option>
  <option value="/">/</option>
  <option value="*">*</option>
</select>

<input type="number" id="n2" value="0"/>

<button id="bt-Calc"> =  </button>

<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```js
 function calc() {
    
      var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n1").value);
      var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n2").value);
      var oper = document.getElementById("operators").value;
    
      if(oper === "+")
      {
        document.getElementById("result").value = n1+n2;
      }
      else if(oper === "-")
      {
        document.getElementById("result").value = n1-n2;
      }
      else if(oper === "/")
      {
        document.getElementById("result").value = n1/n2;
      }
      else if(oper === "*")
      {
        document.getElementById("result").value = n1*n2;
      }
      document.getElementById("operation").value = n1 + oper + n2 + "=" + document.getElementById("result").value;
    }
```

```html
  <input type="number" id="n1"/>
      <input type="number" id="n2"/>
    
      <select id="operators">
        <option value="+">+</option>
        <option value="-">-</option>
        <option value="/">/</option>
        <option value="*">*</option>
      </select>
    
      <button onclick="calc();">sum</button>
      <input type="text" id="result">
      <input type="text" id="operation">
```